# Reading CSV file. UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 336: character maps to

Tags: python, opencsv, readlines

Trying to read two CSV files based on a function but when reading one (yelp.csv) I encounter an error:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 336: character maps to**

I tried the encoding but the error persists. I had identified the issue is when using .readlines(). Not sure how to fix this issue.

```
def readDataFromFile(fileName, seperator, encoding="utf8"):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as panelf:
        panelf.readline()   # skip header
        lines = []
        data = panelf.readlines()
        for line in data:
            line = line.strip("\n").split(seperator)
            lines.append(line)
        return lines

    panelData = readDataFromFile("Desktop/panel.csv", ",", encoding="utf-8")
    yelpData = readDataFromFile("Desktop/yelp.csv", ",", encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

The encoding variable is not used. Try:

```py
def readDataFromFile(fileName, seperator, encoding="utf8"):
    with open(fileName, 'r', encoding=encoding) as panelf:
        panelf.readline()   # skip header
        lines = []
        data = panelf.readlines()
        for line in data:
            line = line.strip("\n").split(seperator)
            lines.append(line)
        return lines

panelData = readDataFromFile("Desktop/panel.csv", ",", encoding="utf-8")
yelpData = readDataFromFile("Desktop/yelp.csv", ",", encoding="utf-8")
```